# What site is best to ask about household appliances?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am having a few issues with my iron at the moment and have searched for similar questions but there's doesn't appear to be a site. More specifically my question is:

**How do I de-calc an iron when the button becomes too hot to hold in?**

There are a few other related(ish) questions I have. Is there like a site for household questions or would such a site have to be proposed in Area 51?

Comment: Similar questions appear to be appropriate on [lifehacks.se].

Comment: I was thinking lifehacks but they seem more about unusual solutions rather then how-to's if I'm reading the [on-topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guide right

Comment: The impression I got was not so much "unusual" solutions as the sort of ideas you might come up with by thinking "outside the box" - that is, they'd only be "unusual" because people aren't encouraged to actually think about the problem at hand; they're encouraged to follow the provided instructions more-or-less robotically.

Comment: … … ……… wait? Wait till the iron cools down? Use gloves? Maybe needlenose pliers? Stating make/model, what you have tried and why it didn't work will help get you a valid answer.

Comment: @Won't I am not posting the question here as it would clearly be off topic. I am just trying to find out what site would be appropriate to ask the question. Obviously, when I post the actual question I will include more details than just the tile.

Answer (score 4):

DIY might be suitable. They have an [appliances](/questions/tagged/appliances) tag

> For questions relating to powered consumer products that perform some value-added task within a home, including but not limited to hot water heaters, stoves/ovens, dishwashers, refrigerators, etc. For questions specifically relating to furnaces or air conditioners, see the "hvac" tag.

There's at least [one question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44966/how-to-get-limescale-out-of-water) about kettle scaling that's not closed.

Check out the site's [help centre](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and maybe try it's [meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're still unsure.

If that DIY doesn't fly then [lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com) may suggest some clever workaround to get the job done. They certainly have questions on [cleaning things](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/how-to-clean-inside-of-straw/18875#18875) and a [cleaning](/questions/tagged/cleaning) tag.

The lifehacks cleaning tag description is

> Tips and tricks relating to cleaning clothing, objects etc. quickly and easily. Please also use another applicable tag (e.g., [clothing], [kitchen], etc.), as THIS TAG IS AMBIGUOUS.

Comment: Small-appliance questions are [off-topic on DIY](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/why-are-small-appliance-questions-off-topic)